# HTTP POST Compress/Decompress files with .tgz, .gz extensions in Java

Tags: java, post

I am trying to upload files to a URL(www.xyz.com) using HTTP PUT/POST from my Java client.
The Java client is standalone and  it does not use any HTML pages to upload files it purely on the server side.

Now, I have some queries with compressing/decompressing files of format .tgz and .gz extensions.
If i want to upload any file of type .tgz or .gz is it necessary to first uncompress the file, read each entry,process and then later after processing again compress the file by writing each entry that has been read into a archive for uploading to a URL.

Is it necessary to do that everytime for any type of formats in Java? 
I am using the HTTPClient and we just need to provide the file path and call the executeMethod(). Is this correct or as said earlier, do I have to compress and decompress file here? The following is my code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
PostMethod postMethod = new PostMethod(url);

client.setConnectionTimeout(8000);

File f = new File("C:\\Softwares\\Jars\\2012326767.tgz";
System.out.println("File Length = " + f.length());

postMethod.setRequestBody(new FileInputStream(f));
postMethod.setRequestHeader("Content-type",Not SURE);
```

Also what should be the content type for .tgz and .gz formats?
Can you please provide your views here as I have been stratching my head on this for a long time now.

Thanks,

vikeng21

Answer (score 0):

There's an example on apache's website: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html. Look for Custom protocol interceptors.

Comment: Got it working. Actually no compression/decompression of the files is required when we do a file upload using the HTTP Client api. Its a direct upload provide correct path and you are done. don't forget to specity the correct Content-Type.